# Sharing on Child Records when OWD on PARENT is Private

Tags: sharing

I have one custom object and which has PARENT as Account.

owd ON account is Private.

When I logged in as user, I can see  child records created by other users as well.

What might be the reason?

Comment: What is the Org-Wide Default on the child object? Does the user have View All, View All Data, or Modify All Data? Are there sharing rules in place? There are _many_ factors you need to investigate to understand specific sharing outcomes.

Comment: owd on child is Controlled By Parent, and the user does not have view all data or modify all data access